# Is there a way to change constraints on Xcode for different devices?

Tags: ios, xcode

My Xcode product was developed on Xcode 10, using the iPhone 11 template and all the view controllers are perfectly aligned.

To make my app more diverse I need to change the size of buttons etc but when I switch the device to say an iPhone 8 or iPhone 4 and change the constraints and switch back to the iPhone 11 view the images are working off the new constraints even though I used the 'vary traits' button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is another way to do this, but I get the device screen and change the size for me works changing the biggest one's and smallest one's screens, but you can create a list of sizes for each different resolution

```
   extension UIDevice {
        var hasNotch: Bool {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                let bottom = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.safeAreaInsets.bottom ?? 0
                 return bottom > 0
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }

        public var iPhoneX: Bool {
            return UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436
        }
        public var iPhone: Bool {
            return UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
        }

        public var smallScreen: Bool {
            return screenType == .iPhones_5_5s_5c_SE || screenType == .iPhones_4_4S
        }


       public enum ScreenType: String {
            case iPhones_4_4S = "iPhone 4 or iPhone 4S"
            case iPhones_5_5s_5c_SE = "iPhone 5, iPhone 5s, iPhone 5c or iPhone SE"
            case iPhones_6_6s_7_8 = "iPhone 6, iPhone 6S, iPhone 7 or iPhone 8"
            case iPhones_6Plus_6sPlus_7Plus_8Plus = "iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6S Plus, iPhone 7 Plus or iPhone 8 Plus"
            case iPhones_X_XS = "iPhone X or iPhone XS"
            case iPhone_XR = "iPhone XR"
            case iPhone_XSMax = "iPhone XS Max"
            case unknown
        }
        public var screenType: ScreenType {
            switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
            case 960:
                return .iPhones_4_4S
            case 1136:
                return .iPhones_5_5s_5c_SE
            case 1334:
                return .iPhones_6_6s_7_8
            case 1792:
                return .iPhone_XR
            case 1920, 2208:
                return .iPhones_6Plus_6sPlus_7Plus_8Plus
            case 2436:
                return .iPhones_X_XS
            case 2688:
                return .iPhone_XSMax
            default:
                return .unknown
            }
        }

        public var buttonsizeheight: Int {
            switch UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height {
            case 960:
                return 10
            case 1136:
                return 20
            case 1334:
                return 25
            case 1792:
                return 28
            case 1920, 2208:
                return 30
            case 2436:
                return 33
            case 2688:
                return 35
            default:
                return 20
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

well you can change or set constraint by using this below code by using it in your class so, you can set your view for iphone and ipad.

```
    struct Device {
// iDevice detection code
static let IS_IPAD             = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad
static let IS_IPHONE           = UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone
static let IS_RETINA           = UIScreen.main.scale >= 2.0
static let SCREEN_WIDTH        = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width)
static let SCREEN_HEIGHT       = Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
static let SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH   = Int( max(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
static let SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH   = Int( min(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )
static let IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH  < 568
static let IS_IPHONE_5         = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568
static let IS_IPHONE_6         = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667
static let IS_IPHONE_6P        = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736
static let IS_IPHONE_X         = IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 812
}
```

now you can set constrain like this:==

```
    if(Device.IS_IPHONE_5 || Device.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS){
    //--- set your constrain for iphone 5 and 4
    }else if(Device.IS_IPAD){
    //--- set your constrain for ipad
    }else{
    //--- set default constrain
    }
```